# Session variable turns out null

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Page1.aspx.cs
I am using `Session["var1"] = "TestCheck";`

Now in Page2.aspx,
This same session variable `Session["var1"]` turns out `null`:

```
string var1 = Session["var1"].ToString();
```

as gives me an error:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

Thanks
SC

Comment: Is Page2.aspx always being loaded after Page1.aspx? Are you putting var1 into the Session on page load? Can you give any more details?

Comment: See http://carso-owen.blogspot.com/2007/02/enablesessionstate-aspnet-most-common.html for common errors.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with that code. You must be attempting to access the Session variable before it's set or something is wrong with your Session state.

Comment: please chk some where you will use Session.Abandon()

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover the basics:
Page1 was accessed first and in the same browser window as page2?
Session variables are not access before the page_load event?
web.config is setup to support session state?

Comment: Page1 is accessed first and in the same browser then a class file, then page2.aspx.

Comment: At what point in the page life cycle are you accessing session?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if cookies aren't enabled on the browser or session has expired.

Make sure you don't have cookies disabled and that your session expiration isn't set too low.